# View not working with url alias

Tags: drupal

My view is working with

```
www.localhost/drupal/node/13
```

but not with

```
www.localhost/drupal/challenge/13
```

I have changed the `node/13` to `challenge/13` using URL alias. Even my page path settings are:

```
challenge/%
```

It is just linking to its node rather than displaying the view.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 3):

Your two alias settings are conflicting with eachother ... Views is trying to stake a claim to `challenge/13`, but your alias table is saying "No, no, no. `challenge/13` is supposed to point to `node/13`"

URL aliases have the last say in deciding where a URL points, so the URL ends up sending you to `node/13`

If you delete the alias entry via `admin/build/path/list` and rebuild your menus, it should work correctly.